# Showing different name of ForeignKey in form

Tags: python, django, python-3.3, django-1.5

i have this Form:

```
class Trida(models.Model):
    název=models.CharField(max_length=20)
    tridni_ucitel=models.ForeignKey(Ucitel, blank=True, null=True)
    predmety=models.ForeignKey(Predmety, blank=True, null=True)
```

When i have this as HTML form, the ForeignKey name is just name of the object (here "Ucitel"
) and " object". I want to change it to show different name (first name and last name). How?

Answer (score 1):

Define it inside your model class as follows:

```
def __unicode__(self):
    return self.first_name + self.last_name
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be what you are looking for - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#verbose-field-names

Answer (score 0):

Define the default string representation on the target model:

```
class Trida(models.Model):
    název=models.CharField(max_length=20)
    tridni_ucitel=models.ForeignKey(Ucitel, blank=True, null=True)
    predmety=models.ForeignKey(Predmety, blank=True, null=True)

class Ucitel(models.Model):
    firstname=models.CharField(max_length=20)
    lastname=models.CharField(max_length=20)
    ...

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s %s' % (self.firstname, self.lastname)
```

If you are using Python 3, use `__str__()` instead of `__unicode__()`.

This is covered in the first page of the Django Tutorial: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/